# Does this scatter plot suggest non-linearity?

Tags: regression, assumptions, scatterplot, nonlinearity, linearity

As part of assumption testing for ordinary least squares (OLS), I am examining the linearity between the variables in my model. I'm using scatterplots between the independent variables (IVs) and dependent variable (DV) to do this. I'm not sure if the graph below violates the linearity assumption or not. It seems that there is no relationship between my IV (dominance) and DV (leadership potential)... yet, there's also a slight quadratic shape (inverted U-shape) present. Is this problematic enough to require a transformation? Or, can I assume linearity between these variables and proceed with OLS? Thanks!

[image]

*Updated to add residuals vs. fitted plot.

[image]

*Updated to add jitter plot with LOESS imposed.
[image]

Comment: It looks fine, usually you would fit the regression and plot the residuals vs fits and then assess linearity.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron! The residuals vs fits plot (now included above) looks quite similar, so it looks like the linearity assumption has been met. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Forgot to tag you, @CameronChandler

Comment: Two issues: (1) the data are obviously discrete, so you cannot tell from the graph how many data points are on each dot, and this matters a great deal in assessing the curvature of the response function. The solution is to show the jittered scatterplot.  (2) The simplest way to assess the degree of curvature is to superimpose the LOESS fit (calculated from the raw, non-jittered data) over the jittered scatterplot.  Then you will have a better idea of the degree of curvature in your process, and can decide whether you need to do something about it.

Comment: Thanks so much, @BigBendRegion. I've included a new scatterplot above with the LOESS fit line imposed. There is a slight curvature, but I'm not sure if it's enough to violate the linearity assumption?

Comment: Is this likert-type data? If so, it appears you have a response item(s) with little variation at the mid-point (i.e., neutral response). Is this safe to say? I'm just curious given the way the data is anchored on both sides.

Comment: @ThomasBilach. The IV is actually a manipulation check measure. The measure uses a Likert scale but my manipulation was for high vs. low only. So that's why there is little variance in the middle. I am hoping to use my manipulation check as an IV in my regression model but had some concerns after seeing the plot above.

Comment: @Christa Curvature always exists to a degree; i.e., linearity is never true except in the cases where $X$ is binary or when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But you should never try to "prove" linearity, because it is like trying to prove that 1+1 =3. The conclusion from your plot is that there is a dip of the average value for high $X$, suggesting curvature. But  it does not appear to be strong curvature, and may be partly explainable by chance alone.  Subject matter will help here: does the dip have an explanation? Is it important/useful? Does the linear approximation to it work well enough?